# Powershell : Start Job and copy file not working

Tags: powershell, file-copying, start-job

I try to use jobs in powershell but after many try it's doesn't works :(
So to sumarry my code is a powershell form with a richtextbox, the user put many computername and the start-job should copy sources file into each temp folder. I use Windows shell copy to have the time for each copy for the user.

I try $line / $($line) / $Global:line but same result, the copy doesn't works, outside the start-job the copy works perfectly.

```
$ImportLog = "$PSScriptRoot\text.txt"

foreach ($line in $richTextBox1.Lines)
{

     $myjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

          param ($ImportLog,$line)

          $line | Out-File $($ImportLog) -Encoding ascii -Append #Works
          $ImportLog | Out-File $($ImportLog) -Encoding ascii -Append #works

          $FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = "&H8&"
          $objShell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
          $objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace("\\$($line)\C$\Temp")
          $objFolder.CopyHere("$PSScriptRoot\Folder", $FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG)   

     } -ArgumentList @($ImportLog,$line)

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job

}
```

If you have a solution ?
Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: You are not passing `$PSScriptRoot` to the job.

Comment: Great ! That's works, I was thinking $psscriptroot, was a native variable so i don't add it into the job :/ Thanks a lot !